# How do I install BURG?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, burg

I found the source in launchpad for 11.04 and 10.10 but I don't know how to install or compile it.

Comment: Originally, you didn't state what distribution you wanted it for...

Comment: @nickguletskii Yes he actually did but someone edited the title.

Comment: @Uri Herrera Oh... Jorge, why didn't you follow "► clarify meaning without changing it"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update: The PPA mentioned below doesn't currently provide packages for 13.10/saucy and newer releases. You could try to install the 13.04/raring packages by modifying the corresponding sources.list file in `/etc/apt/sources.d/` but that is not a recommended workaround.

---

## 11.04 and 11.10

I can't answer directly how to compile the source.  However, I've tested the following on a virtual guest install on oneiric.

Note if you look at the series available [for the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7En-muench/+archive/burg) it will tell you which distro version this PPA has been compiled for.  At the time of writing - 11.04 (Natty), 11.10 (Oneiric), 12.04 (Precise)

*as all stuff that changes your boot - back things up first with a good image backup*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install the remaining packages:

```
sudo apt-get install burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

During the installation you will be asked to select the drive you want to install on - press the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to "*" the drive you want for example `/dev/sda`.

---

**Linked Questions:**

1. [How to automatically update burg after a kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4905/how-to-automatically-update-burg-after-a-kernel-update)
2. [What BURG Themes are Available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50643/what-burg-themes-are-available)
3. [How do I install burg themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50646/how-do-i-install-burg-themes/50647#50647)

Comment: Hi can I install BURG in kubuntu 12.04 x64 bit?

Comment: I cant see any particular reason why in should not work in kubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu.  I've never tested these combinations - so I would advise you to image backup your installation first.

Comment: excellent - let us know the result - perhaps you can edit the answer to reflect what you find?

Answer (score 4):

First, install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

Now, actually install it (replace hd0 with the device to install it to):

```
sudo burg-install "(hd0)"
```

And update it:

```
sudo update-burg
```

And test it using the emulator:

```
sudo burg-emu
```

[Source.](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1679-how-to-install-burg-in-ubuntu-)

Answer (score 3):

Also worth looking at is Super-Boot-Manager, this allows you to configure Grub, Burg  and Plymouth, through a simple GUI and a revert to GRUB option

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install buc super-boot-manager
```

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/super-boot-manger-make-easier-and-intuitive-configuration-of-grub-burg-and-plymouth.html