# How to install Burg theme in Ubuntu 12.04 (Alpha 2)?

Tags: burg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BURG?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61725/how-do-i-install-burg)

Search on the web I cannot find any way to install Burg theme for Ubuntu 12.04 (Alpha 2) however there's a successful solution for Ubuntu 11.10. Anyone who knows, share it please.

At last, I find a solution for this question: follows the commands in Terminal:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
4. sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg *(if you installed Windows and Ubuntu in the same HD, usually Windows for 1st partition and Ubuntu for 2nd partition)*
5. sudo burg-emu

And you can use F3 to choose resolution of Grub menu, F2 to choose theme, press key 'f' to hide the old kernels.
Restart the computer and you will see the grub menu themed.