# How to install BURG on dual-boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu machine?

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I'm relatively  new to Linux/Ubuntu, but I've set up my new machine as dual-boot with 11.10 and Windows 7. I'd like to replace GRUB with BURG to get a nice graphical boot menu.

The machine is set up with two drives, with Windows on the first drive (/dev/sda) and Ubuntu on the second (/dev/sdb). The BIOS is set to boot from the first drive (as it was when I only had Windows installed) so when installing Ubuntu, I selected /dev/sda as the location for the MBR. Now I get the GRUB menu on starting the machine and can boot successfully into both OS's.

I intended to install BURG through Super Boot Manager / Burg Manager, but /dev/sda doesn't appear in the list of options.

How to set this up given the configuration described above?

Answer (score 2):

[Grub Customizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/change-the-grub-boot-order-for-ubuntu-11-10/100246#100246) could be a good idea - you can configure GRUB and BURG with this tool. But be sure you [installed BURG](https://askubuntu.com/a/61737/46531) first.