# BURG for ubuntu 12.10

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, burg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BURG?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61725/how-do-i-install-burg)

Hey guys I just shifted from win 7 to ubuntu with dual boot. and dont like the looks of grub so would like to install burg..would like to know that burg is compatible with 12.10 or not. And if yes then please let me know exact steps to download it.

Also is there any way to change the looks of my desktop?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install BURG?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61725/how-do-i-install-burg) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen

Answer (score 0):

To Install Burg:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

Now to make  BURG integrate the HardDisk enter the following command in terminal:

```
  sudo burg-install "(hd0)"
```

Remember to substitute ‘hd0′  with the drive on which your MBR is installed.

Now update burg:

```
  sudo update-burg
```

Finally, run the following to test and set your theme:

```
 sudo burg-emu

 burg4
```

Press F2 To change theme .

Press F3 to change resolution

If you want to use  another easy way to configue burg, you need to install Burg- manager, for this check our previuos post.

Here are the hot-keys defined in the boot menu:

```
* t – Open theme selection menu
* f – Toggle between folding mode
* n – Jump to the next item with the same class
* w – Jump to the next Windows item
* u – Jump to the next Ubuntu item
* e – Edit the command of current boot item
* c – Open a terminal window
* 2 – Open two terminal windows
* h – Display help dialog (only available in sora theme)
* i – Display about dialog (only available in sora theme)
* q – Return to old grub menu
* F5/ctrl-x – Finish edit
* F6 – Switch window in dual terminal mode
* F7 – List the folded boot items
* F8 – Toggle between graphic and text mode
* F9 – shutdown
* F10 – reboot
* ESC – quit from the current popup menu or dialog.
```