# burg problem after update

Tags: burg

After an update of my kernel, the burg doesn't starts anymore, instead the grub came up when I've restarted my system. I tried update-burg, but doesn't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/4905/how-to-automatically-update-burg-after-a-kernel-update

Answer (score 1):

You should run `sudo burg-install /dev/sda`, too (with replacing sda by the device which boots first).

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click the check button if you accept this answer.

Comment: To replace what ?  sda is replaced with what ?